# Maven running RPM plugin before building children

Tags: maven

I have a parent pom with two children. The two children build to a common target folder, and the parent builds an RPM (with the codehaus rpm-maven-plugin) from that folder. At least, that's how I want it to work. If I specifically build the children before building the parent, it works. But if I clean and then build from the parent, it'll try to build the RPM before it builds the children, and complains that the files are missing.

How can I specify to build the children before running the RPM plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must simply create a separare child which contains the confinguration for the rpm-maven-plugin and defined the appropriate dependencies to the other childs and the new child will automatically build after the others.